# Vimeo subtitles flutter

Tags: flutter, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player, flutter-video-player

there is any way to get video subtitles & captions in any player of Vimeo in flutter ? I tried a lot of packages but not supported captions, I attempted to upload an SRT file to my Vimeo videos, but unfortunately, any player did not support the feature.

Thanks

I am trying to reading the documentation of the Vimeo API but didn't get any solution and I am trying this packages in flutter : [vimeo_video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/vimeo_video_player) and [vimeo_player_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/vimeo_player_flutter) and [pod_player](https://pub.dev/packages/pod_player)